# Magento frontend take too long to respond

Tags: magento2.3, error, https, apache, xampp

[image]
Magento frontend is taking too long to load(~2hrs). In browser's network tab the request remains in pending state throughout. Meanwhile the Admin Backend is loading fine.

Debug logs:

[2021-04-02 07:21:02] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []

[2021-04-02 07:21:02] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'top.navigation.links' tries to reorder itself towards 'op.search', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper_schedule_block1' and '' respectively. [] []

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you run code profiler to determine the run time of each PHP file.
You may refer [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html)

Comment: i have done that and here is the result. could you please help me out with it.                              layout_render  takes 5,311.676078 seconds.